# Объединение commit через atom с помощью squash

Tags: git, github

Запускаю команду

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Выскакивает окно:

```
pick 6ad59ec Добавил rename , checkIP
pick 2dbd852 Изменили list.json
pick daaf645 Добавили list.csv
pick a8926be Изменили list.json
pick 8a64774 Изменили list.json и увеличили delay

# Rebase bb7e3bb..8a64774 onto bb7e3bb (5 commands)
#
# Команды:
# p, pick <коммит> = использовать коммит
# r, reword <коммит> = использовать коммит, но изменить сообщение коммита
# e, edit <коммит> = использовать коммит, но остановиться для исправления
# s, squash <коммит> = использовать коммит, но объединить с предыдущим коммитом
# f, fixup <коммит> = как «squash», но пропустить сообщение коммита
# x, exec <команда> = выполнить команду (остаток строки) с помощью командной оболочки
# b, break = остановиться здесь (продолжить с помощью «git rebase --continue»)
# d, drop <коммит> = удалить коммит
# l, label <метка> = дать имя текущему HEAD
# t, reset <метка> = сбросить HEAD к указанной метке
# m, merge [-C <коммит> | -c <коммит>] <метка> [# <строка>]
# . создать слияние используя сообщение коммита оригинального
# . слияния (или использовать указанную строку, если оригинальное
# . слияние не указано). Используйте -c <коммит> чтобы изменить
# . сообщение коммита.
#
# Эти строки можно перемещать; они будут выполнены сверху вниз.
#
# Если вы удалите строку здесь, то УКАЗАННЫЙ КОММИТ БУДЕТ УТЕРЯН.
#
# Но если вы удалите все, то процесс перемещения будет будет прерван.
#
```

Самый нижний это самый последний коммит, я хочу все до него объединить и его сделать конечным. Написано, что строки будут выполнены сверху вниз,

```
squash 6ad59ec Добавил rename , checkIP
squash 2dbd852 Изменили list.json
squash daaf645 Добавили list.csv
squash a8926be Изменили list.json
pick 8a64774 Изменили list.json и увеличили delay
```

и получаю это

```
error: нельзя выполнить «squash» без указания предыдущего коммита
Вы можете исправить это с помощью «git rebase --edit-todo», а потом запустив «git rebase --continue».
Или вы можете прервать процесс перемещения, выполнив «git rebase --abort»
```

Почему так? Надо оставить верхний pick а остальные сделать squash ?

Comment: Да, нужно наоборот, т.е. брать какой-то комит как pick, а после него уже можно использовать squash/fixup.

Comment: Не логично получается как то. Что будет при раскладе 1-pick 2-squash 3-squash 4-pick , где 4-pick мой последний комит? К 1 или 4 комиту он приклеит 2 и 3?

Comment: к первому, т.е. предыдущему, комиту. В подсказке же пишет `объединить с предыдущим коммитом`.  Все тут логично. Идея в том, что сделал коммит. А потом что-то нужно добавить. Поэтому новый коммит добавляется к предыдущему

Comment: понятно, спасибо